# How do I fix a ' list index out of range' error?

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm a beginner programmer currently learning Python and I'm programming a game for the first time.

The name and result of the winner is written to an external file and can be read from and displayed in the form of a table.

However, I am getting an error here:

```
sort = sorted(results, key = itemgetter(0), reverse = True)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is the whole function for reference:

```
def leadTable():    
  results = []
  with open('winnerScores.txt', 'r') as file:
      r = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ',')
      for row in r:
          results.append(row)
      sort = sorted(results, key = itemgetter(0), reverse = True)
      print(" \n\n\n==================== Leaderboard Table ====================")
      print(" Score\t  Name\t")
      print("____________________________________________________________\n")
      for row in sort:
          print ("|",row[0]," \t " ,row[1]," "*(9-len(row[1]))," ","|")
  print("____________________________________________________________\n\n\n")
```

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file has empty lines, which `csv.reader` is returning as empty lists. You should skip them when filling in `results.

```
for row in r:
    if len(row) >= 2:
        results.append(row)
```

I used `>= 2` because the code that prints the leaderboard requires `row[0]` and `row[1]` to be filled in.

Comment: I didn't know that csv.reader could return empty lines as empty lists so this was very helpful and resolved the error, thank you!